# How to render a Xamarin forms View to an image to increase performance?

Tags: c#, ios, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

If I create a View with a Layout that is quite complicated and has many nested layers it tends to become quite slow to translate around the screen. If I know the layout will not change can I render it to an image and replace the layout with the image?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a similar problem (but targeting iOS only in my case).

Try https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIView.SnapshotView/ to get an UIView with a screenshot from any UIView.

```
UIView view = ...
UIView viewSnapshot = view.SnapshotView(true);
```

I don't know of any cross platform or Xamarin.Forms solution for this.